# I want to generate a HTML view of an xml file through jersey .How do I perform this task?

Tags: jersey

My XML file is present at "D:..." location I want a HTML view of an XML file through jersey.I want my jersey code to take an input from user in form of an XML file and return a HTML view of it.

Thanks in advance.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentData>
  <GeneralInformation ExcelNumber="107" ExcelName="Car107" UplodedByUser="Super@12" UserId="637" />
  <row CarName="i10" CarCode="877566" Engine="Diesel" />
  <row CarName="i20" CarCode="877567" Engine="Petrol" />
  <row CarName="Swift Desire" CarCode="877568" Engine="Diesel" />
  <row CarName="Indigo" CarCode="877569" Engine="Petrol" />
</DocumentData>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide the HTML format you are expecting? Also share your code, to show that you have tried something.

Comment: Hi  Bentaye,
Actually I want to develop a jersey that take XML from user and rendered a HTML view of that XML to user.

Comment: Do you know already how to parse your XML file? and how to create the HTML code from your XML?

Comment: Yes I have that code.

Comment: I added an answer with an overview of how to do it, if you already have your HTML generated, you might only need to look at the end of it, regarding the endpoint definition.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read and parse your XML file into a Java object or a Map or anything you want so you can extract a structure like shown below:

```
String excelNumber = "107";
String excelName = "Car107";
String uplodedByUser = "Super@12";
String userId = "637";

List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
table.add(new String[] {"i10", "877566", "Diesel"});
table.add(new String[] {"i20", "877567", "Petrol"});
table.add(new String[] {"Swift Desire", "877568", "Diesel"});
table.add(new String[] {"Indigo", "877569", "Petrol"});
```

Then from there, you can generate your HTML String, here is a sample code using the variables above:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<table border=1>");
sb.append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>Code</td><td>Engine</td></tr>");
for(String[] row : table) {
  sb.append("<tr>");
  sb.append("<td>");
  sb.append(row[0]);
  sb.append("</td>");
  sb.append("<td>");
  sb.append(row[1]);
  sb.append("</td>");
  sb.append("<td>");
  sb.append(row[2]);
  sb.append("</td>");
  sb.append("</tr>");
}

String html = "<html>" +
    "<header><title>Your Page Title Here</title></header>" +
    "<body>" +
    "Excel Number: " + excelNumber + "<br>" +
    "Excel Name: " + excelName + "<br>" +
    "Upbload By: " + uplodedByUser + "<br>" +
    "Excel Number: " + userId + "<br>" +
    sb.toString() + "<br>" +
    "</body>" +
    "</html>";
```

And finally you need your end point, using the `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)` annotation to signify you are returning HTML

```
@GET
@Path("/yourPath")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String xmlData() {
  return your generated HTML;
}
```

You can now simply call your endpoint in a web browser

```
http://url/yourPath
```

This is what I get in the browser

[image]